# Inner Join in LINQ to SQL Not Working

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5

What's wrong with my code? For the Funcionario table and the Projeto table are underlined in red ...

```
DataContext db = new projfuncionarioDataContext();

var query = from p in db.Funcionario
            join c in db.Projeto on p.Cdfunc equals c.Cdfunc
            select new
            {
              ID = p.Cdfunc,
              Produto = p.Nome,
            };

GridView1.DataSource = query;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604931/getting-data-source-is-an-invalid-type-when-binding-linq-query-to-gridview

Comment: What is your error? Can you bind to a single table (with zero joins)?

Comment: "Funcionario" and "Projeto" tables are underlined in red...

Comment: I am putting it in Page_Load... this is no problem, right?

Comment: Are you programming in Visual Studio? Were "Funcionario" and "Projeto" suggested by Intellisense? If not, what *is* suggested by Intellisense?

Comment: Page_Load is usually a good place to bind, so I don't think that's your issue.

Comment: Could you please explain in detail the error you are encountering? All we have is a description of a problem...but no specifics of the actual error.

Comment: The intelisense dont find "Projeto" or "Funcionario" properties

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        {
            DataContext db = new projfuncionarioDataContext();
            

            var query = from p in db.Funcionario <<<<(underlined in red)
                        join c in db.Projeto<< (underlined in red) on p.Cdfunc equals c.Cdfunc
                        select new
                        {
                            ID = p.Cdfunc,
                            Produto = p.Nome,
                        };

            GridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

Comment: It sounds your dbml file's table names don't agree with your expectations.

Comment: Well if Intellisense doesn't suggest "Projeto" or "Funcionario", then that hints at your problem. Does Intellisense suggest *any* table names? And how did you generate your dbml file in the first place?

Comment: from the database explorer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DataContext db = new projfuncionarioDataContext();
```

Should be:

```
projfuncionarioDataContext db = new projfuncionarioDataContext();
```

Comment: +1 Wow... I can't believe I and everyone else didn't notice this for such a long time!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
GridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your GridView have the [AutoGeneratedColumns property set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901877/cant-bind-a-gridview-to-a-linq-to-sql-result/901940#901940)?